# Disable Animation while in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, rotation

I have a scrollview that has a bunch of photo thumbnails on it just like in the photos app / image picker. When I rotate it, I want to update the scroll view in the middle of the rotation animation (in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`), but I just want it to update without animation (don't want the thumbnails to animate when they move to their new position). How can I accomplish this? I'm using setCenter to move the thumbnails when the rotation occurs. I've tried all of the other rotation methods but they don't get the job done because I need the update to occur while the rotation animation is occurring because that's when it looks the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following works in the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
//insert what you want to not be animated here
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```